# Django Query Annotation Does Not Support math.tan() Calculation

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-q, django-mysql

I have a django 3.2/mysql website. One of the tables, `Flights`, has two columns, `angle` and `baseline`. These two columns are combined in a view to display the value `altitude` using the formula `altitude = baseline * tan(angle)`. I am building a search form for this table, and the user wants to search for flights using a `minimum altitude` and a `maximum altitude`.

My normal approach to the problem is to gather the inputs from the search form, create appropriate Q statements, and use query the table with filters based on the Q statements. However, since there is no `altitude` field, I have to annotate the query with the `altitude value` for the altitude Q statement to work.

It seems that a query annotation cannot use an expression like `math.tan(field_name)`. For example,

```
Flights.objects.annotate(altitude_m=ExpressionWrapper(expression=(F('baseline') * math.tan(F("angle"))), output_field = models.FloatField(),),)
```

generates the error `builtins.TypeError: must be real number, not F`

whereas the expression

```
Flights.objects.annotate(altitude_m=ExpressionWrapper(expression=(F('baseline') * F("angle")), output_field = models.FloatField(),),)
```

does not generate an error, but also does not provide the correct value.

Is there a way to annotate a query on the `Flights` table with the `altitude` value so I can add a filter like `Q(altitude__gte= min_altitude)` to the query? Or, is the best approach to (1) go back to the existing ~1,000 rows in the `Flights` table and add a column `altitude` and insert the calculated value, or (2) filter the `Flights` query on the other search criteria and in python calculate the altitude for each Flights object in the filtered queryset and discard those that don't meet the altitude search criteria?

Note: I have simplified the problem description somewhat by only describing a single altitude value. There are actually 2 altitude values, one in meters and one in feet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Tan`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#tan) database function

```
from django.db.models.functions import Tan

Flights.objects.annotate(
    altitude=ExpressionWrapper(expression=F('baseline') * Tan('angle'), output_field=models.FloatField())
)
```

Comment: Very cool, thanks! I still have a small problem in that the angles are in degrees, and Tan takes radians. I tried `flights = Flights.objects.annotate(
    altitude=ExpressionWrapper(expression=Tan(45 * (Pi/180)), output_field=models.FloatField())
)`, but got the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'type' and 'int'. Not sure how to convert the `angle` field to radians.

Comment: @user1045680 Use the Radians function to convert degrees to radians https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#radians - `Tan(Radians('angle'))`

Comment: Doh! I totally missed that function when I was reading the Django docs on Database Functions. I saw Pi in the list of functions, and went down that path. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: A final question. Does it make the most sense from a performance standpoint to annotate the search queryset with the altitude field and use Q expressions to filter the queryset, as opposed to looping through the queryset and doing the altitude calculation in python and filter that way (e.g create a list of excluded Flights pks and exclude them from the search queryset)?

Comment: @user1045680 99% of the time it will be much slower to do the annotation and filtering in Python

Comment: I ran a little test using the annotation filter versus doing the filtering in python, and found that filtering 617 flight records to find 10 records that met a min-altitude/max_altitude criteria took 0.0277 seconds for the annotation method versus 0.0598 seconds for python filtering. The annotation method was over twice as fast as the python filtering method. Thanks again!